# R using s3 and s4 methods of simulate in the same package

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen, r-s4

I'm puzzled by the error

```
found an S4 version of 'simulate' so it has not been imported correctly
```

I have written an R package that includes a definition for a simulate() method as an S3 method. Because the generic for simulate is already defined, I simply define a simulate.myclass ([simulate.fitContinuous](https://github.com/cboettig/pmc/blob/master/R/wrappers_geiger.R#L87) in my case).

The package also depends on another package that has an S4 version of simulate. When loading my package, I get the S4 version error above.  I'm not sure what is producing the error.

Reproducible example by grabbing the [package from github](https://github.com/cboettig/pmc), or do

```
require(devtools) 
install_github("pmc", "cboettig")
require(pmc)
```

---

**To reproduce** this error from scratch: Create a new package with minimal DESCRIPTION file.  include the DESCRIPTION imports: ouch.  Create a NAMESPACE and add imports(ouch) and S3method(simulate, test).  Create the R directory, add the a trivial R script (I've included roxygen documentation that will generate the NAMESPACE I've just mentioned, but this error can also be created without devtools/roxygen):

```
#' simulate
#' 
#' a test for s3/s4 conflicts
#' @param object who cares?
#' @param nsim guess.
#' @param seed yup
#' @param ... other parameters we will just ignore
#' @return something
#' @method simulate test
#' @S3method simulate test
#' @import ouch
simulate.test <- function(object, nsim = 1, seed = NULL, ...){
  message("This test worked")
}
```

Install the package (document with devtools first if you like), and you get the error.

My best solution so far is to eliminate the S3method line from the NAMESPACE, and export the full function simulate.test instead.  This will pass check and install without warnings, but is clearly an inferior solution.

A different solution is to have ouch in depends as well as imports, and document the S3 method properly (as above).  Then everything works as expected, but the warning message remains.

Comment: Note that using depends instead of imports, and keeping the S3method(simulate, test) line doesn't generate any errors, but also doesn't generate the correct behavior either.

Answer (score 4):

`simulate` is an S3 generic defined in `stats`, so according to section 1.6.2 of "Writing R Extensions" (the example isn't clear -- there are exceptions for generics defined in `base`) your NAMESPACE file should have

```
importFrom(stats, simulate)
S3method(simulate, fitContinuous)
```

The business about "found an S4 method" seems to reflect when the problem was discovered -- trying to add S4 methods to an S3 generic that wasn't visible (the "it" I guess refers the the generic `simulate`).

Comment: the "ouch" package that is imported in my namespace makes stats an s4 method, which is giving me this error.  Try showMethods("simulate") without loading ouch, and you are told that it is not an s4 method.  load library(ouch); showMethods("simulate") and then simulate is now an S4 method.  Not sure how to get around this problem, the s4 error message persists.

Comment: My answer seems to be incorrect, and I don't have an immediate solution; sorry for the mis-information. I'd speculate a work-around would be to selectively importFrom ouch (and not import simulate), or to define an S4 method on simulate, but neither of those should be necessary, IMO.

Comment: Hmm.  The ouch package already defines a simulate s4 method.  I need to use that package's simulate method, so importing it is not an option...